# NS3 bash: ./waf: No such file or directory error

Tags: linux-kernel, ns2, ns-3

```
charlie@charlie:~/Desktop/ns-allinone-3.36.1/ns-3.36.1$ ls
AUTHORS   build-support  CMakeLists.txt   doc       ns3               scratch  testpy.supp  VERSION
bindings  CHANGES.md     contrib          examples  README.md         src      utils
build     cmake-cache    CONTRIBUTING.md  LICENSE   RELEASE_NOTES.md  test.py  utils.py

charlie@charlie:~/Desktop/ns-allinone-3.36.1/ns-3.36.1$ ./waf
bash: ./waf: No such file or directory
```

Could someone help me out to understand why waf module is not installed in my directory?

Comment: Which installation way you are following in that [manual](https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Installation#Installation)? The content of directory `~/Desktop/ns-allinone-3.36.1/ns-3.36.1` which you show doesn't correspond to any of these ways.

Comment: The content you show resembles [that repo](https://gitlab.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev/-/tree/ns-3.36.1). In the README you could see instructions how to build it. These instructions doesn't note `waf`.

Comment: Default is e.g.  `cd ns-allinone-3.36.1/ && ./build.py --enable-examples --enable-tests` https://www.nsnam.org/docs/tutorial/html/getting-started.html ..... Earlier versions had waf configuration/build , new versions have cmake configuration/build →  `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: @Hannet Did you find a solution in the past four months since you asked this? If so, you can answre your own question.

Comment: @KNudLarsen Newer versions don't have the waf file?

Comment: See `ns-allinone-3.36.1/build.py` : build.py seems to use `qmake` for configuration, and `ns-allinone-3.36.1/ns-3.36.1/` is using `cmake` . .... INFO: Please read `ns-allinone-3.36.1/README.md` : "./build.py --enable-examples --enable-tests"

Answer (score 2):

waf build system was removed in version ns-3.36: https://github.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev-git/blob/master/CHANGES.md#changes-to-build-system-3

It is replaced by `ns3` script which is a Python script providing an interface similar to `waf`. Most common commands such as `./waf configure` and `./waf build` are replaced with almost identical `./ns3 configure`, `./ns3 build` etc. Internally, however, CMake build system is used.

You can see the merge request which introduced the change here: https://gitlab.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev/-/merge_requests/460

Comment: Why are all the tutorials still using waf. Causing so much confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `./ns3` command instead of `./waf`